# How can I use javascript to sequentially show one div at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to have a page where one div gets shown and then when the user hits the spacebar, that div gets hidden and the next div gets shown.  I'm starting out using CSS to set the visibility of all divs to hidden, but when I press space nothing happens.

```
$divID = 0;
document.getElementById("div0").style.visibility="visible";

function updateDiv(event){
    // If the spacebar was pressed
    if (event.type == "keydown" && event.which == 32){ 
        // Hide the current div
        $doc.getElementById("div" + $divID).style.visibility="hidden";
        ++divID;

       // Move to next div
       $doc.getElementById("div" + $divID).style.visibility="visible";
    }
}
// Handle events
document.on("keydown", updateDiv);
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed up your code a little to use jQuery (since it was listed as a tag, I assumed it was available). This code lets you set up as many divs as you want, doesn't show a new div until the old one is hidden, and keep the last div visible once it's reached:

```
$('div').hide();
$('div:first').show();

$('body').keypress(function(event) {
    $visdiv = $('div:visible');
    if(event.which == 32 && !$visdiv.is(':last')) {
        $visdiv.hide(400, function() {
            $(this).next('div').show();
        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle for demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/bEGD8/)

Answer (score 1):

You're not very consistent, the variable names change as you go, document is not a jQuery object and has no `on()` method etc.

```
var divID = 0;

document.getElementById("div0").style.visibility="visible";

function updateDiv(event){
    // If the spacebar was pressed
    if (event.type == "keydown" && event.which == 32){ 
        // Hide the current div
        document.getElementById("div" + divID).style.visibility="hidden";
        ++divID;

       // Move to next div
       document.getElementById("div" + divID).style.visibility="visible";
    }
}
// Handle events
$(document).on("keydown", updateDiv);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qDzg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

How about [this fiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/DHJHG/)

```
var ctr = 1;
var max = 3;
$(document).on('keypress', function (e)
{
    if (e.which == 32)
    {
        $('div').hide();
        $('#d' + ctr).show();
        ctr++;

        if (ctr > max)
            ctr = 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`doc` is not defined.

you need `var doc = document;`

You event handler needs to hook to window.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", updateDiv);
```

You don't need `$` in front of regular variables.

You're not really using jQuery, so leave it out.

Comment: Sorry, I changed some things when I pasted it into SO and forgot to change doc.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="bloc selected">Bloc 1</div>
<div class="bloc hidden">Bloc 2</div>
<div class="bloc hidden">Bloc 3</div>
<div class="bloc hidden">Bloc 4</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 32) { 
        var next = ($('.selected').next('.bloc').length > 0) ? 
            $('.selected').next('.bloc') :  $('.bloc1');

        $('.selected').toggleClass('selected hidden');
        next.toggleClass('selected hidden');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
   display:bloc;
}
.hidden {
   display:none;
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Zq8j2/2/